# Run multiple appium sessions parallel in android device

Tags: appium

I want to open two chrome browser instances parallel in real android device using appium. i have started two appium servers with two ports, but when i tried to start second session, first one is killing. Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to start port by using terminal then i had issues too. Open two appium windows and start server on two different ports. Make sure you change the bootstrap port for both.

Comment: Yes i am working on ubuntu so i had only chance to start appium server through terminal. I am using the following commands to start  servers                        "$appium -p 4724 -bp 4726 -U EGxxxxxxxxx"
"$appium -p 4723 -bp 4725 -U EGxxxxxxxxx"    and i am running two chrome browsers are in two different android devices.